# Salesforce Tab and its Object

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, tab, configuration

I can see a tab label "X" in my production org.  How can I find the associated object with that tab?

Comment: What is the behavior that you see when you click this tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to

**Setup -> Create -> Tabs**

You will see a list of all the tabs in your org.  You can see here if your tab is a

- custom object tab, in which case you can see which object.
- Web Tab
- Visualforce tab

**From SF help**

> **Custom Object Tabs** display the data of your custom object in a user
>   interface tab. Custom object tabs look and function just like standard
>   tabs.
>
> **Custom Web Tabs** display any external Web-based application or Web page
>   in a Salesforce tab. You can design Web tabs to include the sidebar or
>   span across the entire page without the sidebar.
>
> **Visualforce Tabs** display data from a Visualforce page. Visualforce
>   tabs look and function just like standard tabs.

See here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_tabdef.htm&language=en_US

Comment: HI Ninja, I've tried that method.  I still did not see a tab label "X" in Create > Tab.  Is there another method?  Thanks

Comment: Can the object be hidden?  I've an Admin role in my org.  Thanks

Comment: @Caky perhaps the "x" you are looking for is a standard tab.  Those will not show up in the Create > Tab area...